# opengl win32 not drawing to screen

Tags: c, winapi, opengl, glew, wgl

I am trying to use `glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red)` to draw a red screen.

The program displays a white screen and the loading icon on the cursor is continually rotating.

I am using glew. I am also using visual studio and i think i have linked to all the necessary libraries. I employed the whole create a temporary context to use the wglCreateContextAttribsARB extension thing.

I have 2 functions for setting things up. the first one creates the window and sets up the pfd: (the editor is not formatting my code correctly so i will leave out the function names)

```
int pf;
HDC hDC;
HWND hWnd;
WNDCLASS wc;
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
static HINSTANCE hInstance = 0;
if (!hInstance) {
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"OpenGL";

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)L"RegisterClass() failed:  ", (LPCWSTR)L"Error", MB_OK);
        return NULL;
    }
}

hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("OpenGL"), TEXT("Pie"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW |
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    x, y, width, height, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

if (hWnd == NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("CreateWindow() failed:  Cannot create a window."),
        TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}

hDC = GetDC(hWnd);

/* there is no guarantee that the contents of the stack that become
   the pfd are zeroed, therefore _make sure_ to clear these bits. */
memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = 32;
pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd);
if (pf == 0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"ChoosePixelFormat() failed:  "
        "Cannot find a suitable pixel format.", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

if (SetPixelFormat(hDC, pf, &pfd) == FALSE) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"SetPixelFormat() failed:  "
        "Cannot set format specified.", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

DescribePixelFormat(hDC, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);

ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);

return hWnd;
```

The second one creates the context and starts the message loop:

```
HDC hDC;
HGLRC hRCt, hRC;
HWND  hWnd;
MSG   msg;

hWnd = CreateOpenGLWindow("minimal", 0, 0, 256, 256, PFD_TYPE_RGBA, 0);
if (hWnd == NULL)
    exit(1);

hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
hRCt = wglCreateContext(hDC);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRCt);
glewExperimental = true;
glewInit();

int attribs[] =
{
    WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
    WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 5,
    WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,
    0
};
hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC, 0, attribs);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, NULL);
wglDeleteContext(hRCt);
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

while (GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
wglDeleteContext(hRC);
DestroyWindow(hWnd);

return msg.wParam;
```

Here is my wndproc:

```
   static PAINTSTRUCT ps;

switch (uMsg) {
case WM_PAINT:
    display();
    BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    return 0;

case WM_SIZE:
    //glViewport(0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_PAINT, 0, 0);
    return 0;

case WM_CHAR:
    switch (wParam) {
    case 27:            /* ESC key */
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return 0;

case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}

return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
```

and here is my display function:

```
glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
glFlush();
```

red is a global variable defined as:

```
GLfloat red[4] = {1, 0, 0, 1};
```

Any help on why it's not drawing to the screen?

Comment: Maybe you forgot `SwapBuffers( some_hdc );` after `glFlush();`

Comment: i had tried that. i now have it working though.

Answer (score 1):

Please put `display()` between `BeginPaint` and `EndPaint`.

> Start the painting operation by calling the **BeginPaint** function.
>   This function fills in the **PAINTSTRUCT** structure with information on
>   the repaint request.
>
> After you are done painting, call the **EndPaint** function. This function
>   clears the update region, which signals to Windows that the window has
>   completed painting itself.

Refer: [Painting the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/painting-the-window)

Use an example to quickly restore the problem:

```
 HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
 case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps; 
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2));         
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);              
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
```

Debug:

[image: 1]

---

```
 HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
 case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;         
            BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2)); 
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
```

Debug:
[image: 3]

Comment: Not quite sure what it was but i started from scratch and got it working. I don't want to compare my new code to this and post a solution either. Still don't quite know what was wrong though.

Comment: @AlanSanchez All right, I mean the loaction of `display()` may influence the dispaly of  background in the `WM_PAINT` which located in the `WndProc` function

Comment: @AlanSanchez Now, it seems that you have solved the issue, do you mind sharing the way you have tried?